# Selenium: How to select a site, from a list of sites that appear in google search?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium. I was searching my name in google and then from the results i want to select one link. 
The code is :

```
public class linkedin {

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      ChromeOptions opt= new ChromeOptions();
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","path");
      WebDriver d = new ChromeDriver(opt);
      opt.addArguments("--start-maximized");
      d.get("http://www.google.com");
      String title=d.getTitle();
      System.out.println(title);
      WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(d, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("gs_htif0")));
      WebElement btnNew = (new WebDriverWait(d, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("_fZl")));
    //WebElement searc = (new WebDriverWait(d, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Neethu Raghavan | LinkedIn')]")));
      WebElement searc=(new WebDriverWait(d,10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Neethu Raghavan | LinkedIn")))); 
      Actions act= new Actions(d);
      act.moveToElement(myDynamicElement).sendKeys("Neethu Raghavan");
      act.perform();
      act.moveToElement(btnNew).click();
      act.perform();
      act.moveToElement(searc).click();
      act.perform();
   }
}
```

Till searching it works well and the results comes. But after this nothing happens.

The error i get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: 
Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.linkText: Neethu Raghavan | LinkedIn (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
System info: host: 'INENRAGHAN1L1C', ip: '10.171.40.246', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91'

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9), userDataDir=C:\Users\raghan1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir19884_11542}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=55.0.2883.87, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 9e89b95716b724c5d5e06751ce1aaf5d
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:265)
    at linkedin.main(linkedin.java:31)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Neethu Raghavan | LinkedIn"}
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 46 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
System info: host: 'INENRAGHAN1L1C', ip: '10.171.40.246', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9), userDataDir=C:\Users\raghan1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir19884_11542}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=55.0.2883.87, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 9e89b95716b724c5d5e06751ce1aaf5d
*** Element info: {Using=link text, value=Neethu Raghavan | LinkedIn}
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor8.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:368)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByLinkText(RemoteWebDriver.java:425)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByLinkText.findElement(By.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:360)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:895)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$000(ExpectedConditions.java:41)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:205)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:201)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$22.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:651)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$22.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:644)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:238)
```

Comment: Neethu, it is much easier to solve the problem than the way you have attempted. get (google.com), sendkeys(), wait and click. There isnt really a need of Actions!

Comment: You have mentioned that the results are shown. But the error is coming from the line before, in which you are waiting for link with the text containing your name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Neethu try this code.

```
driver.get("http://google.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib"));
name.sendKeys("Neethu Raghavan");
driver.findElement(By.id("_fZl")).click();
Thread.sleep(2500);          // wait for 2.5 seconds
```

After above code execution you will be able to select any of the website, which you want to click.

In your case, number of listed sites are showing after searching your name from google. like site names as "facebook" "linkedin" etc.

suppose, you want to click on `linkedin` site. so find webelement using xpath locator.
so your rest of the code look like this below code snippet.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://in.linkedin.com/in/neethu-raghavan-8312a839']")).click();
```

Comment: I am geeting the search resukts. What i actually want was, select one from that results.

Comment: I tried the same code, but I  not being redirected to any of the links. @jainish                                                                                 Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9), userDataDir=..akesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false,
Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//a[@href='https://in.linkedin.com/in/neethu-raghavan-8312a839']}

Comment: I have tried the same code, And it works fine for me in both the browsers like `firefox` and `chrome`

Comment: Setup for chrome browser.`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
 driver = new ChromeDriver();
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`